# How to Mark Items In a list in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am having a little problem figuring something out in an app I'm making, any of you who might be able to help your help will be highly appreciated so much. I have tried several solutions but still no luck.

I have two Items inside my body and they both have an IconButton and the problem is that when I click the IconButton it changes on both Item. I want to make it change only on one button and not all. Here is the part of the code for you

```
Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
   child: MyItems("Cheese burger" , Colors.red, "50")
),
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  child: MyItems("Marshal Burger" ,Colors.grey, "23")
),
```

`And this is how I created MyItems`

```
  IconData icon = Icons.favorite_border;

  Material MyItems(String foodName, Color color, String price) {

    return Material(
      color: color, elevation: 0.0,
      shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("$foodName : R$price",

                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  new IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(icon, size: 35.0 ,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () => _onPressed(foodName,price)),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

`And this is the function called from the IconButton on pressed.`

```
void _onPressed(String name, String price) async {

    SharedPreferences savedCart = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String addedToCart = savedCart.getString('$name');

    if (addedToCart == null) {
      setState(() {
        icon = Icons.favorite;
      });
      savedCart.setString('$name', "$price");
    }
    else {
      setState(() {
        icon = Icons.favorite_border;
      });
      savedCart.remove('$name');
    }

  }
```

I want to be able to mark the Icon without changing the other, I kinda have an idea why it is not working I just can't figure out how to solve it

Comment: Please share as much information as possible relevant to your problem. If you have an idea let the people trying to help you know what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is simple, you pass same widget `IconData` `icon` to both of them, so they will both change when that `icon` changes, in order to fix it you need to separate them with different `IconData`, here is an example

```
IconData icon1 = Icons.favorite_border;
IconData icon2 = Icons.favorite_border;
```

then you need to do one of two things separate functions `_onPressed()` to do diffent things on each request, or help it define which `IconData` should be changed..
I would go with the second option, like this:
assuming our foodName(s) is ['apple', 'banana']..

```
void _onPressed(String name, String price) async {

    SharedPreferences savedCart = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String addedToCart = savedCart.getString('$name');
    var tempIcon;


    if (addedToCart == null) {
          if(name == 'apple'){
              icon1 = Icons.favorite;
          } else {
              icon2 = Icons.favorite;
          }
      savedCart.setString('$name', "$price");
    }
    else {
          if(name == 'apple'){
              icon1 = Icons.favorite_border;
          } else {
              icon2 = Icons.favorite_border;
          }
      savedCart.remove('$name');
    }
    setState(() {});

  }
```

and simply into code pass the different `IconData`

```
Material MyItems(String foodName, Color color, String price) {

    return Material(
      color: color, elevation: 0.0,
      shadowColor: Color(0x802196F3),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("apple : 50",

                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  new IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(icon1, size: 35.0 ,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () => _onPressed('apple',50)),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text("banana : 25",

                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text("",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  new IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(icon2, size: 35.0 ,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () => _onPressed('banana',25)),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```